# How to make android app's background image repeat without cropping pictures

Tags: android

I have set a repeat background image in my app, but the background image cropped and I want it to be repeated and fill in the whole screen without cropping. Maybe round up or round down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the dimension of the View by getMeasuredWidth()

And use Canvas and Bitmap to draw a just-fit background for it

say your picture is 100 x 50 and the view is 635 x 50

```
int viewWidth, picWidth. viewHeight;
Bitmap pic;
Paint paint;
// set corresponding values in the variables above

Canvas c=new Canvas();
Bitmap b=Bitmap.createBitmap(viewWidth, viewHeight,Config.ARGB_8888);
c.setBitmap(b);
int noOfPics= viewWidth/picWidth;

int margin=(viewWidth-(noOfPics*picWidth))/(noOfPics-1);

for(int i=0;i<noOfPics;i++){
    c.drawBitmap(pic, i*picWidth+margin*(i-1),0,paint);
}
```